# How to hide my PHP file in the /var/www directory?

Tags: apache-httpd

I have bind my vps ip with my_domain.com. Every PHP file which I saved in the /var/www  directory will be displayed when to input my_domain.com in firefox by other people.
Now I want to hide my PHP file in the /var/www/ directory, not to be seen by others.
How to set configuration on my Apache2 (to run on debian)?
Some PHP file in the /var/www/ directory can be seen by others, some PHP file in the /var/www/ directory can't be seen by others, how to set it?

Comment: What about using .htaccess parameters in the affected directory?

Answer (score 0):

use `.htaccess` file.

Add this line, replacing the files needed to be hidden:
`IndexIgnore file1.php file2.php`

Save, then restart/reload apache. Make sure `AllowOverride` is set to `All` inside `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/your-config-file` in `<Directory /var/www>` section.

Another method (still using .htaccess or config file)

Add this:

```
<files filetohide.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Then restart/reload apache2.

**Do note that I HAVE NOT tried this.**